# How to get previous value Subject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have the following Subject:

```
  private active = new Subject<P>();
  prev: Custom<any>;

  set(p: P): void {
    this.active.next(p);
  }
```

I want to extract data from `active` subject and set it to `prev` like this:

```
 set(p: P): void {
     this.prev = this.active;
     this.active.next(p);
 }
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're better off using `BehaviorSubject` here. It holds the current value and also has `value` getter to get it.

```js
private active = new BehaviorSubject<P>(null);  // <-- default value required
prev: Custom<any>;

set(p: P): void {
  this.prev = this.active.value;
  this.active.next(p);
}
```

But this doesn't actually look so clean. How exactly are you intending to use the `prev` value? Perhaps there's a cleaner way using `ReplaySubject` with buffer 2.

#### Update: avoiding synchronous `.value` getter

I could come up with 2 ways to use the previous value from a stream.

1. A straight way with the `pairwise` operator. It'll emit the last value and current value as an array. One down side it doesn't emit the first value since there is no current previous state yet. It could be adjusted with the `startWith` operator.

```js
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { startWith, pairwise} from "rxjs/operators";

export class AppComponent {
  subSource = new Subject<any>();
  sub$ = this.subSource.pipe(
    startWith(null),
    pairwise()
  );

  constructor() {
    this.sub$.subscribe(val => console.log("pairwise:", val));

    this.subSource.next(1);
    this.subSource.next(2);
    this.subSource.next(3);
  }
}

// expected output:
// pairwise: [null, 1]
// pairwise: [1, 2]
// pairwise: [2, 3]
```

2. If you do not wish to have a default value at the beginning, you could use `ReplaySubject` with buffer 2 and use `scan` operator to emit only previous and current values.

```js
import { ReplaySubject } from "rxjs";
import { scan } from "rxjs/operators";

export class AppComponent {
  replaySubSource = new ReplaySubject<any>(2);
  replaySub$ = this.replaySubSource.pipe(
    scan((acc, curr) => {
      acc.push(curr);
      return acc.slice(-2);
    }, [])
  );

  constructor() {
    this.replaySub$.subscribe(val => console.log("replay subject:", val));

    this.replaySubSource.next(1);
    this.replaySubSource.next(2);
    this.replaySubSource.next(3);
  }
}

// replay subject: [1]
// replay subject: [1, 2]
// replay subject: [2, 3]
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zmdesg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

As for the question about the default value using `find`. No I don't think it's dirty to use `find` there. In fact, `find` is there to fetch a specific element based on a predicate, so I don't see any wrong in your usage.

#### Update: emit as `{prev: .., active: ..}`.

You need only to pipe in a `map` operator to the end and emit as per the requirement.

```js
sub$ = this.subSource.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  pairwise(),
  map(([prev, active]) => ({ prev: prev, active: active }))
);

// expected output:
// pairwise: {prev: null, active: 1}
// pairwise: {prev: 1, active: 2}
// pairwise: {prev: 2, active: 3}
```

I've also adjusted the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hznsbh?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to reflect the changes.

Comment: But this doesn't actually look so clean. - Could you comment, what is wrong? I just want to store prev state and activate this next time

Comment: This goes against the async nature of observables since we are "cheating" with the synchronous `value` getter. In fact, some loathe the `value` getter and actively advise to avoid it and considers it anti-pattern. But if it works for you, then it works for you.

Comment: Okay let is imagine we have two observables: active: Observable<string>, and prev: Observable<string>. Each time when I set `active` I should store prev value. Then restore prev value to active. How to to that not using  sync approach?

Comment: And ho to set default value to `private active = new BehaviorSubject<P>(null); ` from list of outside? Could I use it like `private active = new BehaviorSubject<P>(list.find((item) => item.default);` it look ugly

Comment: I've posted an update to fetch both previous and current values from a single subscription using two different ways. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot. How can I map pairwise result to object with keys: {one: value, two: value}?

Comment: @AlexandraBalmush: You need only to pipe in a map operator to the end. I've updated the answer and the Stackblitz.

Comment: I need to get prev value only by click, I have tried this, but does not work:

`clickHandler() {
    this.sub$.subscribe(val => console.log("pairwise:", val.prev));
  }`

Comment: So, when user need he can set a prev value as current

Comment: It seems to work for me in Stackblitz when I do `console.log("pairwise:", val.prev)`.

Comment: Yes, but I want to get prev value only by click, not always, is it possible to subscribe only after click?

Comment: @AlexandraBalmush: Yes it's possibly using RxJS `fromEvent` function. But it's completely another question. I'd say this question has been solved. Please try using `fromEvent` with a mapping operator like `switchMap`. If you run into issues, you could write another question.

Comment: ReactiveX so "genius". Write a lot crutches to implement simple things.